# Deformation parameters of a nucleus

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, scattering

How are the deformation parameters (quadrupole, hexadecapole etc) of a nucleus mathematically related to the reduced transition probabilities $B(El)$ values obtained experimentally?

Comment: You've asked a whole series of very short questions on nuclear shape and multipole moments. This kind of question doesn't really given us any idea of your level of preparation. You also haven't engaged with people when they've provided answers or comments, and haven't accepted many answers to these question. I haven't been trying to answer because I would need to bone up and I'm busy in "real" life. But in light of the history I'm getting less motivated every time I see another short-short question. Could you expand on what you *do* and *don't* understand here?

Comment: Ok I apologize. Actually I have just started reading up this topic about shapes and deformations and rather than reading up books, I wanted to know how others would explain it simply in their own words which would make me understand the concept better. If i post a long question, then it is considered to be a 'broad question; no specificity'; hence i had been posting short questions as I read up the literature day by day. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: I'm sorry. I must have come across as too short, I was hoping I could help you write better question. Your question have reasonable breadth, but we don't know if the one sentence version would work for you, or you need a few paragraphs, or if you need the "lies to children" pop-sci version? You are using enough jargon that I would guess it is not the latter, but beyond that I'm lost. Were the answer that you got [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/188537) and [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/188003) at the right level of detail? Too little? Too much?

Comment: A side note on site mechanics: you can "accept" one answer per question by selecting the check-mark beside the answer. This lets people know that you got a solution to your problem, and awards 15 rep to the author of the answer. Also you can write LaTeX-alike math by enclosing it in single $'s for inline or double for block-typeseting.

Comment: Those questions that you linked to, the answers provided some clarity but some things are still unexplained. A little bit more detail would have been helpful, particularly [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/188537/why-do-nuclear-multipole-moments-of-charge-density-vary-with-isotopes). Moreover, I have been up-voting answers and also check-marking the ones I find best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that the deformation parameters are related to the diagonal matrix elements of the multipole operators, while the reduced transition probabilities $B(El)$ are related to the off-diagonal matrix elements.

As a specific example, the quadrupole moment (directly related to the deformation parameter $\beta$) of a nucleus in its ground state is given by $$Q_{gs} = \langle \Psi_{gs} | \mathcal{O}(E2) | \Psi_{gs} \rangle $$ with the electric quadrupole operator given by
$$ \mathcal{O}(E2) = \sum_{i} e_{i} r_{i}^2 Y^{2}_{m}(\theta_{i},\phi_i). $$
The reduced transition probability for an $E2$ transition from an initial state $\Psi_i$ to a final state $\Psi_f$ is given by 
$$ B(E2;i\rightarrow f) = \frac{\left| \langle \Psi_{f} \| \mathcal{O}(E2) \| \Psi_{i} \rangle \right|^2}{2J_i+1}. $$
An analogous relationship hold for other multipoles.

In the case where the nucleus is modelled as a rigid rotor with an intrinsic quadrupole moment $Q_0$, then (see Bohr and Mottelson Volume 2 for a derivation, or else [this](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Shape_deformations_in_atomic_nuclei)) the static (i.e. lab-frame) quadrupole moment is given by 
$$Q = \langle J K,2 0 | J K \rangle \langle J J, 2 0 | J J \rangle Q_0
= \frac{3K^2-J(J+1)}{(J+1)(2J+3)}Q_0$$
where the brakets are Clebsch-Gordan coefficients and $K$ is the projection of $J$ on the symmetry axis of the intrisic system.
The reduced $E2$ transition probability between two rotational states with the same intrinsic deformation is given by
$$ B(E2; KJ_i \rightarrow K J_f) = \frac{5}{16\pi}e^2Q_0^2 |\langle J_i K, 2 0 | J_f K \rangle|^2.$$
Finally, relating $Q_0$ to the quadrupole deformation parameter $\beta$, we have 
$$Q_0 \approx \frac{4}{3}\beta\langle \sum_i e_ir_i^2 \rangle$$
(again, see the previous references for more detail).

Comment: I agree with your answer. What I wanted to know was how to relate the reduced transition probability to the deformation parameter directly. That is something I have been unable to do so far.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your question. The relationship between the transition probability and the deformation parameter only makes sense if you assume a common deformation parameter for the initial and final state, as is the case for a rigid rotor. I've updated my answer to include some formulas for a rigid rotor model.

Comment: ok so I mainly need to know how are the different multipole moments related to the deformation parameters! That solves the confusion. Thanks :) Could you provide some hints as to how are the higher moments related to β??

Comment: $\beta$ is the coefficient of $Y^{2}_0(\theta,\phi)$ in the multipole expansion of the nuclear surface shape, so it only relates to the quadrupole moment. Other moments are related to different parameters in that expansion.